# check form requirements and then send data with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to send form data as json to my device (with XMLHttpRequest).
My form have multiple required fields, and should not submit if mandatory fields are empty. But form data sends even field empty!
I searched, and add `event.preventDefault();` but it's not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>first assignment</title>
    <script>
      function curlcheck() {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var user_id = document.getElementById("user_id").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
        var theUrl = "/submit_test";
        xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ "ProgMode": user_id, "pass": pass }));
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                //document.getElementById("ajax_res").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                console.log("success");
                }
        }
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="somebox"></div>
    <ul>
      <h3>Team 1 Online Exam System</h3>
    </ul>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <div name="form header" class="formhead">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p><span id="loginerr" class="err_alert"></span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="login_box">
        <lable for="user_id">User ID</lable>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter User ID" id="user_id" required>

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" required>

        <button id="but" type="submit" onclick="curlcheck(); return false">Login</button>

      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `if(user_id !== null && user_id !== "" && pass !== null && pass !== "") .....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5, you do not need to check it by yourself, you can call the `reportValidity()` method to do the validation.

```js
function curlcheck(form){
        var user_id = document.getElementById("user_id");
            var pass = document.getElementById("password");
  
        if (user_id.reportValidity() && pass.reportValidity()){
                  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
                  var theUrl = "/submit_test";
                  xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
                  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                  xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ "ProgMode": user_id.value, "pass": pass.value }));
                  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    //document.getElementById("ajax_res").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    console.log("success");
                    }
                }
               }
        return false;
    }
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" onclick="return curlcheck(this);">
      <div name="form header" class="formhead">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p><span id="loginerr" class="err_alert"></span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="login_box">
        <lable for="user_id">User ID</lable>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter User ID" id="user_id" required>

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" required>

        <button>Login</button>

      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: validation is worked fine by your suggestion. But null data is send. ==> {"ProgMode":{},"pass":{}}

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

If required data empty then return false from `curlcheck` function.

```
<script>
  function curlcheck(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var user_id = document.getElementById("user_id").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;

     if (user_id === "" || pass === "") {
       return false; //or show required message 
     }

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
    var theUrl = "/submit_test";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ "ProgMode": user_id, "pass": pass }));
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //document.getElementById("ajax_res").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            console.log("success");
            }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: form validation by your suggestion worked fine. but after add event in function curlcheck(), data not send by ajax